# Log Scaled Y-Axis in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, histogram, tensorboard, tensor

Is it possible to visualize y-axis in log-scale in TensorFlow's Tensorboard?

I have the following histogram (distribution) of weights in the first layer of my neural network: [image: Histogram Example]

From the image it seems that weight distribution is hardly changing at all. Though true, I want to see the variation in log-scale (y-axis). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can always define your own summaries with `log(abs(weights))`.